# C# Displaying Image from Database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ashx

I am having some issues displaying an image from a SQL Server database in a .NET application using C#. I've got the save part of the image working and it is storing the image as a series of byes in the database, but now I am running into issues trying to display it. Here is what I have:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public class ShowImage : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        Int32 empno;
        if (context.Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
            empno = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["id"]);
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("No parameter specified");

        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        Stream strm = ShowEmpImage(empno);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);

        while (byteSeq > 0)
        {
            context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteSeq);
            byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
        }
        //context.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
    }

    public Stream ShowEmpImage(int empno)
    {
        string conn = CodProbs.Main.GetDSN();
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn);
        string sql = "SELECT CoverPhoto FROM Galleries WHERE GalleryID = @GalleryID";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GalleryID", empno);
        connection.Open();
        byte[] img =                                                                   System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar()));
    try
    {
        return new MemoryStream((byte[])img);
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}

public bool IsReusable
{
    get
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is not resulting in any syntax errors and seems like it should be working. After stepping through it with the debugger, I can see that it is grabbing the proper data from the database. However, I receive an error of: "The image ... cannot be displayed because it contains errors."

Any ideas on what the issue is here?

**UPDATE** Storing the image

```
public static int AddGallery(GalleryDS galleryDS)
        {
            DataRow gallery = galleryDS.Tables[0].Rows[0];
            int result = 0;
            string sql = @"insert into Galleries (Title, Description,     GalleryCategoryID, CreateDate, CreatedBy, CoverPhoto)
                        values (@Title, @Description, @GalleryCategoryID, @CreateDate, @CreatedBy, @CoverPhoto)
                        select scope_identity()";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Main.GetDSN()))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", gallery["Title"]);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", gallery["Description"]);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GalleryCategoryID", 0);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreateDate", DateTime.Now);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedBy", gallery["CreatedBy"]);
            command.Parameters.Add("@CoverPhoto", SqlDbType.VarBinary, Int32.MaxValue);
            command.Parameters["@CoverPhoto"].Value = gallery["CoverPhoto"];
            conn.Open();
            result = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
            conn.Close();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: You are only assigning 4096 bytes -- is that enough? If the image is bigger, I wonder if there's corruption there?

Comment: you code isn't complete.  what comes after 'byte[] img =' ??

Comment: byte[] img = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar()));

Comment: Try flushing the output stream after the last write.

Comment: Why return a `MemoryStream`? Isn't the byte array that contains the array sufficient?

Comment: Also, lots if `IDisposable` resources that should be wrapped in `using` statements.

Comment: I'm now using the code below as suggested by @ChrisLively. I'm still running into an issue though if you could check that out and give me any advice. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ShowEmpImage method shouldn't convert it to a stream and then write it.  That's a waste of time.

Change the definition to:

```
public Byte[] ShowEmpImage(int empno) {
    string sql = "SELECT CoverPhoto FROM Galleries WHERE GalleryID = @GalleryID";
    Byte[] result = null;

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CodProbs.Main.GetDSN())) {
        using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn)) {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GalleryID", empno);
            conn.Open();
            result = (Byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

To call it use the following:

```
    Byte[] empImage = null;
    empImage = ShowEmpImage(empno);
    context.Response.Buffer = true;
    context.Response.Clear();
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
    context.Response.Expires = 0;
    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=yourimagename.jpg");
    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", empImage.Length.ToString());
    context.Response.BinaryWrite(empImage);
```

Side note:  ALWAYS wrap unmanaged objects with the `using` clause.  It cleans up after you and is simply good practice.  Especially for database connections.

Comment: This definitely makes more sense, thanks. Still getting the same error, though.

Comment: @user2363182: see above.  Now if for some reason you are still getting an error then I would take a look at the part storing the image in SQL server.  It's likely that you aren't putting the entire image in.

Comment: Also note that this version writes the name of the file AND size to the browser.  This helps the browser know what to do with it.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I've gone with what you've suggested and am still running into the same problem, so perhaps it is how I am storing the image. I updated my original post to display how I am storing the image into the database.

Comment: to store it into the DataSet that I'm using in that method, I'm simply using a FileUpload control and taking the FileBytes value of it and storing it into a column in the DS of type System.Byte[]

Comment: after updating to your most recent edit, I am now getting a casting error when executing the query: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Byte[]'

Comment: Any idea on how to get around this? Anybody?

Comment: @user2363182: The only reason for you to get the cast problem is if the first column of the data returned from the query is a varchar instead of a varbinary.  What is the actual code you currently have?  In other words, have you changed the query?  `ExecuteScalar` tells the command object to return the first column in the first row of the result.